# Babel not preprocessing files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, babeljs, webstorm

I having trouble configuring my karma.conf.js file to do unit test on ES6 via Webstorm, using babel and Karma.

What I am trying to do here is to run the test on `'/test/BaseElement.test.js'`

When launching the test, i am receiving the following error:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Which means to me that the preprocessing has not properly been done.

Here are my dependancies from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.3",
"jasmine": "^3.5.0",
"jspm": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
"karma": "^5.0.1",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "^8.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
"mocha": "^7.1.1"
```

And my Karma.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
        config.set({
            basePath: "",
            frameworks: ["jasmine"],
            Preprocessors: {
                //'./Control/**/*.js': ['babel'],
               // './lib/**/*.js': ['babel'],
                //'./Module/**/*.js': ['babel'],
               '../lib/Element/BaseElement.js': ['babel'],
                '../test/BaseElement.test.js ': ['babel']
            },
            babelPreprocessor: {
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
                },
            plugins: [
                '@babel/core',
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-babel-preprocessor'
            ],
            files: [
                {pattern: '../lib/Element/BaseElement.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
                { pattern: "*.test.js", type: "module", included: true }
            ],
            //reporters: ['jasmine'],
            port: 9876,
            colors: true,
            logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
            autoWatch: true,
            browsers: ["Chrome"],
            singleRun: true,
            concurrency: Infinity
        });
    };
```

When I output using the --log-level debug flag, nothing about preprocessing appear.

The files are located like this:

in root : `package.json`

in root/test : `BaseElement.test.js` and `karma.conf.js`

in `root/lib/Element BaseElement.js`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is preprocessor instead of Preprocessor.